# Logic Expression using Binary Tree (DSA) Python

Tags: python, algorithm

**i need a algorithm has a expression as input and return truth table**

**input : String expression**

ex : "(A AND B)=>R OR D"

**output : truth table**
[output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHQUL.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this for a course you are taking? What sort of tools do they use? It seems like course material is better than SO for this.

Comment: @tdelaney it's course i take in university

Comment: @thomaskeefe i tried tree with recursion but when i'm combining all thing it's not work